# Unable to call a JS function properly through a onclick created via innerHTML in js

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to call the function loadInWhat using an onclick and populate my input id="what" using the value of LI

```
 function createDivBox(data){
        document.getElementById("whatContainer").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("whatContainer").classList.add("ac-container");
        var node = "";
        for (var i=0; i<data.Suggestions[0].Results.length;i++)
        {
            var textnode ='<li value="'+data.Suggestions[0].Results[i].Name+'" onclick="loadInWhat(this.value)">'+data.Suggestions[0].Results[i].Name+'</li>';
            node = node.concat(textnode);
        }
        document.getElementById("whatContainer").innerHTML = '<div class="ac-content"><div class="ac-bd" id="ac-bd"><ul>'+node+'</ul></div></div>';

    }


function loadInWhat(loadStr)
{
  document.getElementById("what").value=loadStr;
}
```

My function dynamically created li elements on the basis of the JSON object data.I want that if i click on any li element the input id="what" field gets populated by its value ie data.Suggestion[0].Results[0].Name

Whenever im passing this.value only '0' is passed.

Answer (score 2):

Value for li tag must be an integer. [Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element).

I would suggest using data attributes instead.

**EDIT: Data attributes example**

Create li like this (I am passing the whole element to the javascript function);

```
var textnode ='<li data-val="'+data.Suggestions[0].Results[i].Name+'" onclick="loadInWhat(this)">'+data.Suggestions[0].Results[i].Name+'</li>';
```

The you can access this value in Javascript like this;

```
function loadInWhat(el)
{
  var loadStr = el.dataset.val;
  document.getElementById("what").value=loadStr;
}
```

Comment: to expand on the answer, data attribute would be like `data-value=....` instead of `value=` and then the onclick would pass `this.dataset.value` instead of `this.value`.

Comment: guess i was editing the answer with the example as you were writing this.